# is it possible to be notified when an angular component finishes loading?

Tags: angularjs

I am using `angular 1.5`'s new `component` feature to compartmentalize various things; in particular I have a `sidenav` slide-out menu.

The `sidenav` needs to run its initialization code *after* other components are finished loading. So far I cannot find anything that helps me break this logic apart. At the moment, I am accomplishing this with a messy hack, like this.

assume html body such as this;

```
<body>
   <container>
      <navigation></navigation>
      <sidenav></sidenav>
   </container>
</body>
```

`navigation` *needs* to finish rendering before the `sidenav` can execute correctly. So in my component files, I am doing this (pseudo code);

#### SideNav Component

```
bindings = {};
require = { Container: '^container' };
```

#### SideNav Controller

```
$postLink = function() { 
   Container['Ready']();
}
```

#### Navigation Component

```
bindings = {}; 
require = { Container: '^container' };
```

#### Navigation Controller

```
$postLink = function() {
   if(Container['Ready'])
      Container['Ready']();
}
```

#### Container Component

```
transclude = true;
```

#### Container Controller

```
pending = 2; // controls that must finish loading
Ready = function() { 
   pending--;
   if( pending > 0 )
      return;
   // code to initialize sidenav via jQuery
}
```

so basically, there is a counter on the container, and each component that I need to be loaded calls a function on the parent that decrements the counter. If that causes the counter to be 0, then the sidenav is initialized.

This feels really caddywhompus, though. Is there any other way to get some form of notification or behavior that can allow me to initialize the sidenav when it is truly the right time?

Comment: What's the specific dependency for the sidenav - the presence of certain dom objects, authentication, data retrieval, etc.?

Comment: The presence of certain DOM elements, and the service that roundtrips to an exposed API to return information that goes in the side bar that is restricted by user and role.

Comment: For instance, if your user account isn't high enough, certain parts of the sidenav menu just won't be there. It all takes place on the server to eliminate putting that logic in the javascript (since that can be edited in the browser)

Comment: Ok, I figured it was something relatively complex. It sounds like you could do something in the $onInit of the sidenav using a timeout that's wrapped in a loop to just test for the existence of all of these things and then only allow it to continue when all are present. That seems to obvious though and I suspect you've already been down that road.

Comment: Hrnm. I had thought about that, I was hoping to find something that didn't need a repeating timeout like that - but it may be all I can do. They don't offer enough in the way of life cycle methods on components yet.

Comment: You know, actually the timeout idea sounds bad. I think a watch in the controller for the sidenav would be cleaner.

Comment: a watch? what would I be watching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably think of a better place to hang these items, but the idea I had with the watch is to do something like this:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<body ng-controller="appController as AppCtrl">
    <div>
        <component1/></component1>
        <component2></component2>
        <component3></component3>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        angular.module("myApp",[])
               .controller("appController", function($rootScope,$scope) {
                    var ctrl=this;
                    ctrl.readyForAction = readyForAction;
                    ctrl.letsParty = letsParty;
                    $scope.$watch("$rootScope.gotBeer && $rootScope.gotPizza && $rootScope.gotHockey",ctrl.readyForAction)

                    function readyForAction() {
                        if ($rootScope.gotBeer && $rootScope.gotPizza && $rootScope.gotHockey) {
                            ctrl.letsParty() 
                        }
                         else
                        {
                            console.log("Not yet!")
                        }
                    };

                function letsParty() {
                    alert("Let's go Red Wings!")
                };
                })
                .component("component1", {
                    template:"<h1>Beer</h2>",
                    controller: function($rootScope) {
                        $rootScope.gotBeer=true;
                    }
                })
                .component("component2", {
                    template: "<h1>Pizza</h1>",
                    controller: function($rootScope) {
                        $rootScope.gotPizza = true;
                    }
                })
                .component("component3", {
                    template: "<h1>Hockey</h1>",
                    controller: function($rootScope) {
                        $rootScope.gotHockey = true;
                    }
                })
    </script>    
</body>
</html>
```

I'm just setting the flags when the controllers are created, but obviously you could set them anywhere. So then you just watch an expression that consists of all of your flags and then when they all evaluate to true you go about your business.

Comment: And actually, I just read your initial question again and I think you could just have a watch on the counter and the fire your code when the counter hits zero.

Comment: This turned out to work the best. Thank you. It's a dizzying problem to deal with. I do hope that Angular 2 has a better mechanism for it.

Comment: This worked for a short time, but then for some reason it stopped. It seems that even putting code inside of `$scope.$watch` or `$rootScope.$watch`, etc - it fires off the instant the component loads, no matter what the values, and it doesn't care if they don't exist.